# Pointfree (or library) function for applying two functions to single input

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I keep reusing lambda expressions such as

```
\x -> (f x, g x)
```

where I apply the same input to two functions and encapsulate the result in a pair. I can write a function capturing this

```
combine :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b,c)
combine f g x = (f x, g x)
```

Now the above lambda expression is just `combine f g`. I have two questions.

1. I'm interested to know if there is a standard library function that does this that I just can't find.
2. Out of curiosity, I'd like to rewrite this function in point-free style, but I'm having a lot of trouble with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. `Control.Arrow` has the function [`(&&&)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-) for this. It has a "more general" type, which unfortunately means that Hoogle doesn't find it (maybe this should be considered a bug in Hoogle?).
2. You can usually figure this sort of thing automatically with [`pointfree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree), which `lambdabot` in `#haskell` has as a plugin.

For example:

```
<shachaf> @pl combine f g x = (f x, g x)
<lambdabot> combine = liftM2 (,)
```

Where `liftM2` with the `(r ->)` instance of `Monad` has type `(a -> b -> c) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b) -> r -> c`. Of course, there are many other ways of writing this point-free, depending on what primitives you allow.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer, and thanks for pointing me to pointfree.

Answer (score 12):

> I'm interested to know if there is a standard library function that does this that I just can't find.

It's easy to miss because of the type class, but [look at `Control.Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html). Plain `Arrow`s can't be curried or applied, so the `Arrow` combinators are pointfree by necessity. If you specialize them to `(->)`, you'll find the one you want is this:

```
(&&&) :: (Arrow a) => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c')
```

There are other, similar functions, such as the equivalent operation for `Either`, which specialized to `(->)` looks like this:

```
(|||) :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
```

Which is the same as `either`.

> Out of curiosity, I'd like to rewrite this function in point-free style, but I'm having a lot of trouble with it.

Since you're duplicating an input, you need some way of doing that pointfree--the most common way is via the `Applicative` or `Monad` instance for `(->)`, for example `\f g -> (,) <$> f <*> g`. This is essentially an implicit, inline `Reader` monad, and the argument being split up is the "environment" value. Using this approach, `join f x` becomes `f x x`, `pure` or `return` become `const`, `fmap` becomes `(.)`, and `(<*>)` becomes the [S combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_Logic) `\f g x -> f x (g x)`.

Comment: Part of the reason the Control.Arrow functions are hard to miss is that Hoogle won't unify type variables with `->`, even if the kinds match, so [Hoogling for `(a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b,c)`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=(a+-%3E+b)+-%3E+(a+-%3E+c)+-%3E+a+-%3E+(b%2Cc)) fails to find `(&&&)`.  ([Hoogling for `f a b -> f a c -> f a (b,c)`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=f+a+b+-%3E+f+a+c+-%3E+f+a+(b%2Cc) works, as does (with a warning) [Hoogling for `(a ~> b) -> (a ~> c) -> (a ~> (b,c))`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+~%3E+b%29+-%3E+%28a+~%3E+c%29+-%3E+a+~%3E+%28b%2Cc%29)).

Comment: Thank you both for this, this is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks Antal for pointing out the `a ~> b` syntax for Hoogle, which I didn't know about.

Answer (score 6):

There are actually quite a few ways of doing this.  The most common way is to use the `(&&&)` function from `Control.Arrow`:

```
f &&& g
```

However, often you have more functions or need to pass the result to another function, in which case it is much more convenient to use applicative style.  Then

```
uncurry (+) . (f &&& g)
```

becomes

```
liftA2 (+) f g
```

As noted this can be used with more than one function:

```
liftA3 zip3 f g h
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for the "use with more than one function" explanation.

Comment: And these can of course be rewritten with `<$>` and `<*>`: `zip3 <$> f <*> g <*> h`. Sometimes this is clearer than using `liftA*`.